# Selective find/replace with sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need to do some find and replace in C++ source code: replace all occurrences of `_uvw` with `xyz` except when `_uvw` is part of `abc_uvw` or `def_uvw`. For example:

```
abc_uvw ghi_uvw;
jkl_uvw def_uvw;
```

should become:

```
abc_uvw ghixyz;
jklxyz def_uvw;
```

So far I came up with the following:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/abc_uvw/\!s/_uvw/xyz/g'
```

This will replace all `_uvw` with `xyz` only in the lines that don't contain `abc_uvw`, which (1) doesn't handle such a case: `abc_uvw ghi_uvw;` and (2) doesn't take into account the second exception, that is `def_uvw`.

So how would one do that sort of selective find and replace with sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(abc|def)_uvw/\1\n_uvw/g;s/([^\n])_uvw/\1xyz/g;s/\n//g' file
```

Insert a newline infront of the strings you do not want to change. Change those strings which do not have a newline infront of them. Delete any newlines.

N.B. Newline is chosen as it cannot exist in an unadulterated sed buffer.

Comment: elegant solution for temporary pattern and easy to add other excluded pattern also +1

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ cat file
abc_uvw ghi_uvw;
jkl_uvw def_uvw;

$ sed 's/abc_uvw/foo/g;s/def_uvw/bar/g;s/_uvw/xyz/g;s/foo/abc_uvw/g;s/bar/def_uvw/g' file
abc_uvw ghixyz;
jklxyz def_uvw;
```

Comment: assuming there is no foo or bar in the file

Comment: I assumed there is  no foo or bar present in your file. Likewise you can replace foo and bar with anyother texts which are not presented in your file.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
sed -e 's/abc_uvw/AAA_AAA/g;        # shadow abc_uvw
        s/def_uvw/DDD_DDD/g;        # shadow def_uvw
        s/_uvw/xyz/g;               # substitute
        s/AAA_AAA/abc_uvw/g;        # recover abc_uvw
        s/DDD_DDD/def_uvw/g         # recover def_uvw
        ' input.cpp > output.cpp

cat output.cpp
```

Comment: assuming there is no AAA_AAA, DDD_DDD in the file

Comment: exactly, that's why I used so weird strings

Answer (score 1):

You should use negative lookbehind. For example, in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!(abc|def))_uvw/xyz/g' file.c
```

This performs a global substitution of any instances of `_uvw` that are not immediately preceded by `abc` or `def`.

Output:

```
abc_uvw ghixyz;
jklxyz def_uvw;
```

Sed is a useful tool and certainly has its place but Perl is a lot more powerful in terms of regular expressions. Using Perl, you get to specify exactly what you mean, rather than solving the problem in a more roundabout way.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/µ/µm/g;s/abc_uvw/µa/g;s/def_uvw/µd/g
     s/_uvw/xyz/g
     s/µd/def_uvw/g;s/µa/abc_uvw/g;s/µm/µ/g' YourFile
```

This is like the other in concept but "escaping" first the temporary pattern to filter on abc and def. I use `µ` but other char is possible, just avoid special sed char like `/`, `\`, `&`, ...